# Blacklist a tag please devs?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging

[database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) is really rather pointless on our site. I would just as soon it was never used as a tag, but at the very least, won't you bulk-remove them so I don't have to bump 10 Qs on our slow frontpage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Trogdor burnination]

Burninated and blacklisted.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you :D